# adding JPanel On JApplet and writing HTML page to run it

Tags: java, applet, japplet

I have a java applet and I want to add a pre-designed Jpanel on my jpanel as a form. My Jpanel form is in another java file called MyForm.java. my JavaApplet class code is:

```
public class JavaApplet extends JApplet{
    @Override
    public void init(){
        Container container = this.getContentPane();
        container.add(new MyForm());
    }
     }
```

My html code to run this page is as simple:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>The Palindrome Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<P>My favorite meat-related palindrome is:
<BR>
<APPLET CODE="JavaApplet.class" WIDTH=600 HEIGHT=100>
A secret if your browser does not support Java!
</APPLET>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

now can I put both .class files (MyForm.clsss & JavaApplet.cleass) in htmls file? Is it necessary to put all of my code in single file?

thank you

Comment: Myself, I'd create a jar file.

Comment: and implemented jar file in the applet tag in the html file ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `MyForm` to a frame instead of the applet.  (You might create a frame in a main method and add it there.)
2. Put those classes in a Jar.
3. Make a (JNLP) launch file for it.
4. Launch the Jar from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

In answer to your specific questions.

> now can I put both .class files (MyForm.clsss & JavaApplet.cleass) in htmls file?

If the loose class files are both in the same directory (and package), they should be found.  Safer though, to use a single Jar.

> Is it necessary to put all of my code in single file?

Java source code file?  No - definitely not.  Classes?  Recommend 1 Jar.

If using a Jar, you'd need an `archive` attribute in the `applet` element.

Comment: Thank you for replying; but I have  question: finally after making jar file and JNLP file; When I want to set <applet> tag in html file; which of this files should be as CODE property? Also is it necessary to make an executable file that contains main method?

Comment: Sounds like a good question for your next question.  Is this question answered?